# What are some authoritative/respected "best known implementation" websites/resources?

Tags: language-agnostic, resources, implementation

**EDIT**:

Wow, the initial response to this question was quite negative. I think I might have triggered some pretty strong emotions by using the word "best"; it seems like a few people latched onto that word and decided to dismiss my question right away.

Obviously, there are many, many situations in which no single approach is "best", or at least, what ends up being the best solution to one problem will often *not* be the best solution for other, even similar, problems. **I get that.** But now let me try to elaborate on the reasoning behind what I'm *actually* asking.

I tend to find it easiest to explain myself using analogies, so here goes. In my current job I work almost exclusively in .NET. .NET has a **lot** of functionality built into the framework. A prime example is the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace, which has a bunch of collection classes that (almost) no .NET developer in his/her right mind would bother re-developing from scratch, because **very good implementations** are already there. If I am working on a problem that requires a doubly linked list, I'm not going to decide, "Okay, time to write a doubly linked list class"; I'm just going to use the `LinkedList<T>` that's already there, or, at most, extend it or wrap it with my own class that adds some extra functionality.

Am I saying the "best" version of a doubly linked list is `LinkedList<T>` from .NET? Of course not. **That** would be absurd. But I highly doubt .NET's implementation of `LinkedList<T>` is drastically different from most other established libraries' implementations of collections that are intended to serve the same purpose (that of a doubly linked list). On the other hand, I am relatively confident that *if I were to write my **own** implementation from scratch*, there'd be a considerable number of issues with it, in terms of robustness, performance, flexibility, etc. for one simple reason: not that I'm stupid, or lazy, or don't care about good code--simply that I'm one person, and I'm not an expert on linked lists, and I haven't thought of everything that needs to be taken into consideration when designing one.

But I happen to be a developer who *does* take an interest in how things are implemented internally. And so it would be nice if I could check out a page where some variant of a well thought-out design for a linked list--*or for any fairly established concept for which robust, efficient implementations **have** been written*--were available to view. (By the way, yes I am aware that the source code for .NET's `LinkedList<T>` is available. I'm just using that as an example; really I am talking about all problems with solutions for which good, working implementations exist.)

Now, I talked about this being something that is **open**; let me elaborate on that. I am *not* talking about sites like SourceForge.net, or CodePlex, or Google Code. These are all sites for hosting **projects**, i.e., applications or libraries tailored for some specific industry or field or otherwise categorizable purpose. What I'm talking about is something *like* this:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Category:Algorithms_and_data_structures

Maybe I should have just provided that link in the first place, as it probably illustrates what I'm getting at better than anything I've written so far. But I think the main point that differentiates what I'm asking about from any other site I've seen is that I was specifically wondering if there could be some way to work on a *new* problem--so, something for which there aren't necessarily any well-known, established implementations, again as in my linked list example--collaboratively, in a wiki-esque fashion, but **not tied to any specific open-source project**.

So, as a conclusion of sorts, I was kind of envisioning a situation like the following: I find myself faced with a new problem. Maybe it isn't common enough to be something that is addressed in a framework like .NET. But it's common enough that some developers here and there are independently working on it. If a website exists like what I'm imagining, maybe at some point one of those developers working on the problem could post an idea on that website, and over time others might discover it and suggest improvements/modifications, and *given enough time and participation*, a pretty darn good implementation might result from all this collaboration. And from there, eventually, something *like* this implementation might be considered fairly "standard", **just like a linked list implementation, or a quicksort implementation, or, I don't know, some well-known pseudo-random number generator.**

Does this make any more sense to anyone now? I feel quite confident that what I'm talking about is not absurd, but hey, if that's what people think, then maybe it is.

---

Open source projects are very popular. Some of these are libraries suited for specific purposes, the best of which include some very well-written code.

However, if you're interested in contributing to an open source project, finding a project that is well-suited to your skills can be quite a task. At the same time, if you're interesting in *using* an open source project in your own work, finding a project that is well-suited to your *needs* can also be difficult, especially when, for example, open-source library X has a lot of functionality you could use, as does library Y, and these two libraries' capabilities overlap so that integrating both into your code could be messy.

We've all seen questions, here on Stack Overflow and elsewhere on the web, posted by one developer: "How would I implement this idea?" and answered by others, often accompanied by a plethora of example code. Sometimes these answers link to an open source project/library that provides functionality similar to what the poster is asking about.

My question is: are there any well-known websites or other sources that are **open in nature** and provide "best-known implementations" for common (or even not-so-common) programming problems, but not associated with any particular open source project?

As a generic example, suppose I have a need for some algorithm that does X. I post a question on SO or some other site requesting ideas, asking for suggestions on how best to implement it. One person points me to project P1, which contains some code that performs something very similar to this algorithm. Another person points me to project P2. Someone else writes some sample code and says, "maybe you could do it like this."

It seems to me, if there are all these different versions of this idea floating around out in the world, it would make sense for there to be a site, somewhat in the vein of Wikipedia, where a quasi-"official" implementation ("official" is not the right word; I'm just having trouble thinking of a better one right now) could be published and modified as improvements are developed/discovered.

I feel like I have stumbled across a few different sites like this in the past, but I'm interested to know if anyone else has found any resources like what I'm describing.

Comment: Wouldn't it be great if there was one authoritative, final repository for all good ideas.  Keep hoping.  And while your at it, remind people to stop improving on other people's ideas because new things keep fragmenting the One Repository for Good Ideas.

Comment: SourceForge is not a repository for "best of" projects.  It is a repository for **any** project.

Comment: @S.Lott: He did say **best known.**

Comment: IME, most of the best ideas, algorithms, code samples and open source projects tend to bubble up to the top of a Google search anyway.

Comment: Isn't this exactly what StackOverflow aspires to be?  If you want to know about the best implementation of an algorithm, just post a question and see what gets voted up... and then make your own decision.

Comment: @Robert: That may be, but the *main* point I was interested in was finding a site that involves collaboration and allows people to make updates to it, much like Wikipedia. Of course it's nice to know how established, existing algorithms/structures are commonly implemented, but I'm just as interested in solutions to new problems that are actually in the *process* of being developed.

Comment: @Daniel: Is it? I was kind of under the impression Stack Overflow is more about answering **any** programming-related question, and not necessarily providing good working implementations of solutions to new problems. It also seems that often when a question *is* posed as "How would I implement this?" the best answer ends up being a rough sketch, or a conceptual outline of what the solution might be, not a concrete implementation (though these are occasionally offered as well).

Comment: -1: After the edit, I no longer get the question.  It's sort of a rant, or a wish for collaborative development of algorithms.  But it's not a question that I can parse.

Comment: Too broad a question. SO is for well defined programming questions. How do I do x with tool y? Are you looking for good learning resources? Ask about that!

Answer (score 1):

The very idea is absurd.  It means that there's one, single opinion on "best-known implementations" with no changes based on other people having better ideas.

It implies a that best practices are static and *can* be accumulated into a single repository.

If they *could* be collected, then Google would have them and would simply charge for access.

Interestingly, they don't have all the best practices.  Interestingly, they have to expend mountains of computing power looking for more information.  Then people (like you) have to read and think and judge and decide.

The read-think-judge-decide is really hard to eliminate.  Unless, of course, you want someone to think for you.  In which case, there are many companies who have a single solution that requires less thinking.  Call Microsoft or Oracle or IBM.  They have solutions that are all in one place, unified best practices, no reading, no thinking, no judging, no deciding required.

**Open -- by definition -- means it's impossible to have a single authoritative source.**

Comment: True, but you probably could come up with something like "a pretty good implementation that a lot of people agree is suitable for use case".    Sure, it's not BEST, but still useful.

Comment: Google wouldn't charge for access.  They'd just display ads.

Comment: @S.Lott: really, *absurd*? That sounds like a knee-jerk reaction to me. To be fair, I did use some poorly chosen words in my original question, namely "best", which I didn't really mean in the objective sense in which you interpreted it. Still, I think you're kind of unfairly representing my question in this response. Anyway, I expanded on my original post, and would be interested to hear any further thoughts you may have (even though originally I was just asking for links, in case people knew of any sites like what I was describing).

Comment: @Dan: Not knee-jerk.  Just logic.  "Single Best" (or "Standard") and "Innovation" are diametrically opposed.  Period.  The "single best" networking protocol for information sharing can't be HTTP -- it's awful.  But there it is.  I can't figure out what you're asking for.

Comment: @S.Lott: The original question was pretty straightforward: does anyone know of any sites like this, and if so what are they. Rather than answer this question you attacked the very notion as absurd, so my edit was an attempt to defend its... non-absurdity? You're right, though; what's left is barely a question anymore. I may take one last (concise) crack at it yet.

Comment: @Dan: I did not "attack" the notion as absurd.  I pointed out that the notion is a contradiction.  "Open" == "Innovative".  "Single Best" or "standard" is the diametric opposite of innovative.  I'm suggesting that there cannot possibly be an answer to the original question that you would find satisfying because your have opposing criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something, maybe not the best implementations. But a book called [Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) contains what is considered by many programmers some of the best patterns to follow!